# Manga in which the female lead is poisonous and the male lead is immortal

Tags: story-identification, manga

Hi I am looking for a manga where the  female lead is poisonous and the male lead is immortal. What I remember is during their marriage ceremony, the male lead licked the tears of the female lead even though these are poisonous. Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this full colour or mostly black & white? Also, can you tell us anything more about the world the story is set in?

Comment: Possibly *Alkaloid Bride*? I'm not in a position to read it, and all of the summaries seem the same (and don't mention immortality). But it is apparently about a poisonous bride, and the cover looks like he's licking tears off of her face.

Answer (score 1):

It is Alkaloid Bride, surprisingly pretty good

Comment: Hi, this answer looks like a possibility!  You can improve it (and earn more reputation) if you add some details about the manga (e.g. character names and descriptions, maybe the blurb or intro text) and a link to a site that has information about it.